# Arithmetic operations in IF loop

Tags: c

What does the below code do? I'm very confused with its working. Because I thought that the if loop runs till the range of int. But I'm confused when I try to print the value of `i`. Please help me out with this.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    static int i;
    for (;;)
        if (i+++”Apple”)
            printf(“Banana”);
        else
            break;
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as an "if loop". The `if` keyword does not create a loop.

Comment: @unwind okay yar..i'll not use it anymore. Thank u

Comment: And please do not use `void main()`; the return type is `int`, and unless you're using C99 or later, you should have a `return(0);` (give or take the parentheses) at the end of `main()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is interpreted as `i++ + "Apple"`. Since `i` is static and does not have an initializer, i++ yields 0. So the whole expression is `0 + some address` or equivalent to `if ("Apple")`.

#### EDIT

As  Jonathan Leffler correctly notes in the comments, what I said above only applies to the first iteration. After that it will keep incrementing `i` and will keep printing "Banana".

I *think* at some point, due to overflows (if it doesn't crash) `"Apple" + i` will yield 0 and the loop will break. Again, I don't really know what a well-meaning compiler should do when one adds a pointer and a large number.

As Eric Postpischil commented, you can only advance the pointer until it points to one-past the allocated space. In your exxample adding 7 will advance the pointer one-past the allocated space ("Apples\0"). Adding more is undefined behavior and technically strange things can happen.

Comment: That's true on the first iteration; on the second, `i` is 1, and the tested expression is 1 plus the same address as before.  This could print a lot of bananas before it stops.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You're right, I didn't even see there was a loop.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It needs not be ever true. `i` is not initialised.

Comment: @JanDvorak: `i` is static; it is initialized to 0.

Comment: @JanDvorak: it's declared `static`, so it's implicitly initialized to 0.

Comment: how long will the loop run ?

Comment: @Praveen Since it's doing output... a long time (unless it crashes in the mean time).

Comment: @Praveen Until it throws a access violation or looks at a memory location whose value is such that the sum is zero.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler how long will the loop runs?

Comment: @dmckee It shouldn't cause an access violation since it doesn't actually dereference it.

Comment: @JanDvorak No, it's undefined once it leaves one-past-"Apples".

Comment: @cnicutar when it will stop executing?

Comment: @cnicutar when `i` overflows and becomes `-"apples"`

Comment: This is the pont at which is becomes clear that Praveen doesn't care to understand, he just wants someone to give him the answer to *"when it will stop executing?"*.

Comment: Sorry yar. I apologize @dmckee. Because as I'm a beginner I needed some clear explanation. With all ur valuable comments i'll make myself understand. Sorry.

Comment: There is no shame in being a beginner--we all were at one time (perhaps excepting Jon Skeet)--but directing a comment of *"when it will stop executing?" at every person who puts in their two bits suggests an unhealthy obsession with getting an answer over understanding what is happening.

Comment: You should probably add to the answer the fact that once `i` exceeds 6 (the length of the string, including the null character), the behavior of the addition of `i` to `"Apple"` is not defined by the C standard, as you alluded to in a comment. With most common C implementations, what will happen is the loop will continue until the sum wraps around the end of the address space. Then the sum will be zero, and the program will stop. Other behaviors may occur. In an implementation with base+offset addressing, the sum might never be zero.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I edited. In the future you can edit yourself, I don't mind :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use `int main(void)` instead of `void main()`.

The expression `i+++"Apple"` is parsed as `(i++) + "Apple"`; the string literal `"Apple"` is converted from an expression of type "6-element array of `char`" to "pointer to `char`", and its value is the address of the first element of the array.  The expression `i++` evaluates to the current value of `i`, and as a *side effect*, the value in `i` is incremented by 1.

So, we're adding the result of the integer expression `i++` to the pointer value resulting from the expression `"Apple"`; this gives us a new pointer value that's equal or greater than the address of `"Apple"`.  So assuming the address of the string literal `"Apple"` is 0x80123450, then basically we're evaluating the values

```
0x80123450 + 0
0x80123450 + 1
0x80123450 + 2
...
```

all of which should evaluate to non-zero, which causes the `printf` statement to be executed.  The question is what happens when `i++` results in an integer overflow (the behavior of which is not well defined) or the value of `i+++"Apple"` results in an overflow for a pointer value.  It's not clear that `i+++"Apple"` will ever result in a 0-valued expression.

Answer (score 1):

This code SHOULD Have been written like this:

```
char *apple = "Apple";
for(i = 0; apple[i++];)
    printf("Banana");
```

Not only is it clearer than the code posted in the original, it is also clearer to see what it does. But I guess this came from "Look how bizarre we can write things in C". There are lots of things that are possible in C that isn't a great idea.

It is also possible to learn to balance a plate of hot food on your head for the purpose of serving yourself dinner. It doesn't make it a particularly great idea - unless you don't have hands and feet, I suppose... ;)

Edit: Except this is wrong... The equivalent is:

```
char *apple = "Apple";
for(i = 0; apple+i++ != NULL;)
    printf("Banana");
```

On a 64-bit machine, that will take a while. If it finishes in reasonable time (sending output to /dev/null), I will update. It takes approximitely three minutes on my machine (AMD 3.4GHz Phenom II).

Comment: This is also what I assumed was meant, but it is just an assumption.

Comment: No, it is not an assumption from my side - I obviously can't tell what you are assuming or not. The original code in this post and my code are functionally identical, just that the original code is much harder to read. [I shall edit to make my code-formatting fix up].

Comment: You code stops on finding the `'\0'` at the end of `"apple"` which the original code does not unless `"apple"` exists in one very special place in memory where the address arithmetic overflows and results in `0`.

Comment: Uhm, yes you are right. I just compiled it, and it keeps printing Banana a lot. And on a 64-bit machine, I expect it may take a while until the address of i and Apple adds up to zero.

Comment: I've updated the post with new code and the runtime to finish on my machine.